# How to reconnect and continue normaly on "Error: MySQL server has gone away" in nodesql and MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, reconnect, mariasql

I get `Error: MySQL server has gone away` from time to time using [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) and [mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql). The application stops working logically. Now I wonder if there is a way to catch this error, reconnect and continue normal operation.

Comment: Have you Googled the error message, possibly adding the name of your programming platform? I'll bet you a beer there's plenty of results.

Comment: I have, but no success for mariasql. The only suggestion I found was to increase `connTimeout`, but this will not really solve the problem when a connection really dies and has to be reinitiated.

Comment: But it seems likely that mySQL oriented advice on the issue will also apply to MariaDB - e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Obviously this error can have many reasons. The client is configured to fire a ping every 60 seconds, so a connection should not time out. Okay I will check the other case, if I can find something. Thanks for the hint, Pekka

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that mariasql reconnects automatically, but make sure you listen to the `error` event, or your application will stop due to uncaught exception error.